# Measure on countable subsets

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X$ be an infinite set and $R$ the collection of all countable subsets of $X$. Is $R$ a $\sigma$-ring?

Yes. A countable union of countable subsets is a countable subset. A difference of two countable subsets is a countable subset.

> Let $\mu$ be a measure on $R$. Show that there exists a function $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that $\mu(A)=\sum_{x\in A}f(x)$ for all $A\in R$.

Take $f(x)=\mu(\{x\})$ for all $x\in X$. Then the equation follows from countable additivity of $\mu$.

> Show that the function $f$ above has to have the following two properties: (1) The set $\{x\in X;f(x)\neq 0\}$ is countable and (2) $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)<\infty$.

Suppose there exists an uncountable number of $x$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$. How does that yield a contradiction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard measure theory trick : Let $A_k = \{x\in X : f(x) > 1/k\}$. Then we claim that $A_k$ is a finite set. If not, then there exist $\{x_n\} \in X$ such that
$$
\mu(\{x_n\}) > 1/k
$$
Let $B = \{x_n\}$, then $B$ is countable, but $\mu(B)$ is not a real number (and i am assuming that that is not allowed).

Hence, $A_k$ is a finite set, so
$$
A = \{x \in X : f(x) \neq 0 \} = \cup A_k
$$
is countable.

Now (2) follows from (1) because the sum int (2) is really $\mu(A)$

Comment: I've seen this trick somewhere before but didn't think of it here. Very nice Prahlad!

Comment: But how does (2) follow from (1)? The sum in (2) is not really $\mu(X)$, because $\mu$ is not defined on $X$.

Comment: But $\mu(A)$ is defined.

Comment: Oh I see, my bad. I didn't see you're referring to that $A$